# optimization problem resolution

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I need to get the value of k that minimizes : $\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+\left( \omega-\omega_{c}\right)^2}}$ under the constraints : $k > 0$ and $\omega \ne \omega_{c} $.
Thank you.

Comment: $\phantom{}$ $k=-\infty.$

Comment: Can you explain we how do you find that?

Comment: Your function is an increasing function in $k$.

Comment: yes but the fonction has two variables k and $\omega$

Comment: Given $\omega$ and $\omega_c\neq\omega$, the minimum for your function is $-1$ and it is attained at $k=-\infty$.

Comment: excuse me, I make some correction. k must be a positive value.

Comment: Then there is no minimum, since your function is continuous in a neighbourhood of $k=0$.

Comment: what is the significance of this expression? what are the parameters  $k$ and $omega$ ?

Comment: $\omega$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and k is a positive real number.